# Get a part from the array

Tags: php, arrays

The following code is converting XML to array. I want to get a sting by the value of [name]. So for example: $..[offerid].. should give 8b5f7fd3806a42ccb0ade9f8309c5587
Who can help me?? :)

```
$xmldata = file_get_contents($XMLURL);
$arr= xml2ary($xmldata);

foreach($arr['m4n']['_c']['data']['_c']['record'] as $result){
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
}
```

The echo result is:

```
Array
(
    [recordHash] => Array
        (
            [_v] => -652572603
        )

    [column] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_a] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => url
                        )

                    [_v] => http://ad.dd.com/ppc/?20910868C187884459&zpar6=DF_1&ULP=[[http%3A%2F%2F]]
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_a] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => title
                        )

                    [_v] => This is the title
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [_a] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => description
                        )

                    [_v] => Aanbod
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [_a] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => offerid
                        )

                    [_v] => 8b5f7fd3806a42ccb0ade9f8309c5587
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping through all of the items using a php [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
$name_to_find = 'offerid';
$value = FALSE;

foreach ($result['column'] as $item) {
  if ($item['_a']['name'] == $name_to_find) {
    $value = $item['_v'];
    break;
  }
}

// Now $value has the value of the entry with the name $name_to_find
```

If you end up finding an entry with the given `$name_to_find`, then `$value` will not be `FALSE` (granted that, you don't have any `FALSE` values :D).